# How to overcome TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to take a file that looks like this:

```
AAA x 111
AAB x 111
AAA x 112
AAC x 123
...
```

And use a dictionary so that the output looks like this

```
{AAA: ['111', '112'], AAB: ['111'], AAC: [123], ...}
```

This is what I've tried

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r") 
readline = file.readline().rstrip()
while readline!= "":
    list = []
    list = readline.split(" ")
    j = list.index("x")
    k = list[0:j]
    v = list[j + 1:]
    d = {}
    if k not in d == False:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(v)
    readline = file.readline().rstrip()
```

I keep getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I know that keys in a dictionary can't be lists but I'm trying to make my value into a list not the key. I'm wondering if I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As indicated by the other answers, the error is to due to `k = list[0:j]`, where your key is converted to a list. One thing you could try is reworking your code to take advantage of the `split` function:

```
# Using with ensures that the file is properly closed when you're done
with open('filename.txt', 'rb') as f:
  d = {}
  # Here we use readlines() to split the file into a list where each element is a line
  for line in f.readlines():
    # Now we split the file on `x`, since the part before the x will be
    # the key and the part after the value
    line = line.split('x')
    # Take the line parts and strip out the spaces, assigning them to the variables
    # Once you get a bit more comfortable, this works as well:
    # key, value = [x.strip() for x in line] 
    key = line[0].strip()
    value = line[1].strip()
    # Now we check if the dictionary contains the key; if so, append the new value,
    # and if not, make a new list that contains the current value
    # (For future reference, this is a great place for a defaultdict :)
    if key in d:
      d[key].append(value)
    else:
      d[key] = [value]

print d
# {'AAA': ['111', '112'], 'AAC': ['123'], 'AAB': ['111']}
```

Note that if you are using Python 3.x, you'll have to make a minor adjustment to get it work properly. If you open the file with `rb`, you'll need to use `line = line.split(b'x')` (which makes sure you are splitting the byte with the proper type of string). You can also open the file using `with open('filename.txt', 'rU') as f:` (or even `with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:`) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 80):

> **Note:**
>   This answer does not explicitly answer the asked question. the other  answers do it. Since the question is specific *to a scenario* and the raised **exception is general**, This answer points to the general case.

Hash values are just integers which are used to compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup quickly.

Internally, `hash()` method calls `__hash__()` method of an object which are set by default for any object.

#### Converting *a nested list to a set*

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7],8,9]
>>> set(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This happens because of the list inside a list which is a list which cannot be hashed. Which can be solved by *converting the internal nested lists to a tuple*,

```
>>> set([1, 2, 3, 4, (5, 6, 7), 8, 9])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, (5, 6, 7)])
```

#### Explicitly hashing *a nested list*

```
>>> hash([1, 2, 3, [4, 5,], 6, 7])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


>>> hash(tuple([1, 2, 3, [4, 5,], 6, 7]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

>>> hash(tuple([1, 2, 3, tuple([4, 5,]), 6, 7]))
-7943504827826258506
```

> **The solution to avoid this error is to restructure the list to have nested tuples instead of lists.**

Comment: what if the list is too big ?? looks that is a good solution but not general enough

Comment: @msh855 is there any size limit? I tested the dictionary with a tuple of size 100,000 and it worked fine for me (I'm using python 3.6)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the reason. That cleared my doubt while trying to solve a problem with 2 approaches and both had the type as 'list' but one was giving this error.

Comment: @msh855 You can't hash a list given size `0` or a  `quadrillion`. Its the issue with the types not the size. **LIST DOES NOT HAVE A `__hash__` METHOD**. A work around is create a `custom_list` type that inherits `list` with a method `__hash__()` then convert your list to use the `custom_list` datatype. still better to use built-in types.

Answer (score 28):

You're trying to use `k` (which is a list) as a key for `d`. Lists are mutable and can't be used as dict keys.

Also, you're never initializing the lists in the dictionary, because of this line:

```
if k not in d == False:
```

Which should be:

```
if k not in d == True:
```

Which should actually be:

```
if k not in d:
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're getting the `unhashable type: 'list'` exception is because `k = list[0:j]` sets `k` to be a "slice" of the list, which is logically another, often shorter, list. What you need is to get just the first item in list, written like so `k = list[0]`. The same for `v = list[j + 1:]` which should just be `v = list[2]` for the third element of the list returned from the call to `readline.split(" ")`.

I noticed several other likely problems with the code, of which I'll mention a few. A big one is you don't want to (re)initialize `d` with `d = {}` for each line read in the loop. Another is it's generally not a good idea to name variables the same as any of the built-ins types because it'll prevent you from being able to access one of them if you need it — and it's confusing to others who are used to the names designating one of these standard items. For that reason, you ought to rename your variable `list` variable something different to avoid issues like that.

Here's a working version of your with these changes in it, I also replaced the `if` statement expression you used to check to see if the key was already in the dictionary and now make use of a dictionary's [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to accomplish the same thing a little more succinctly.

```
d = {}
with open("nameerror.txt", "r") as file:
    line = file.readline().rstrip()
    while line:
        lst = line.split() # Split into sequence like ['AAA', 'x', '111'].
        k, _, v = lst[:3]  # Get first and third items.
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        line = file.readline().rstrip()

print('d: {}'.format(d))
```

Output:

```
d: {'AAA': ['111', '112'], 'AAC': ['123'], 'AAB': ['111']}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason behind this is the list contains list of values. Like:

```
a = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4]]
```

And this won't work with something like this:

```
list(set(a))
```

To fix this you can transform the interior list to tuple, like :

```
a = [(1,2),(1,2),(3,4)]
```

This will work !

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` is happening because `k` is a list, since it is created using a slice from another list with the line `k = list[0:j]`.  This should probably be something like `k = ' '.join(list[0:j])`, so you have a string instead.

In addition to this, your `if` statement is incorrect as noted by Jesse's answer, which should read `if k not in d` or `if not k in d` (I prefer the latter).

You are also clearing your dictionary on each iteration since you have `d = {}` inside of your `for` loop.

Note that you should also not be using `list` or `file` as variable names, since you will be masking builtins.

Here is how I would rewrite your code:

```
d = {}
with open("filename.txt", "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        fields = line.split()
        j = fields.index("x")
        k = " ".join(fields[:j])
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(" ".join(fields[j+1:]))
```

The `dict.setdefault()` method above replaces the `if k not in d` logic from your code.

Comment: while preference is your full right, `not k in d` could confuse a novice as `(not k) in d`, while `k not in d` has no ambiguity

Comment: I would even argue that it is the 'pythonic' way as `not in` is listed as an [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: Yeah, I think my preference probably comes from learning other languages first, where for something like a containment test you wouldn't have operators for this so you would do something like `!a.contains(b)`.  `not in` may be more pythonic, I just find the concept of two word operators more confusing than using an inverse on a boolean expression.

Answer (score -1):

python 3.2

```
with open("d://test.txt") as f:
    k=(((i.split("\n"))[0].rstrip()).split() for i in f.readlines())
    d={}
    for i,_,v in k:
        d.setdefault(i,[]).append(v)
```