# Adding array to dictionary TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

I am unable to add array [3,5] to dictionary linedict = {}. I have check with solution mentioned on [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)
but still error is coming (TypeError: unhashable type: 'list')

```
    links = [links[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(links), 2)]

    for i in range(0, len(links), 1):
        print links[i]

        if links[i] not in linedict:#on this linme
          linedict[links[i]].append( prob)
```

I want to create dictionary of [3,5] value 0.03.

Comment: `links[i]` is a _list_.

Comment: Sorry i edited forgot to mention

Comment: It's a ``list``. You can't hash a ``list`` because they're mutable (and thus their hash could change outside of the control of the dict). You would have to convert it to a ``tuple``

Comment: i have tried with this linedict[tuple(links[i])].append(prob) but the error is still coming as Key Error

Comment: Because the ``in`` keyword is also trying to hash the ``list``, since it's testing the existence of the value as a key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already printing `links[i]`, so it should have come to your attention that each element of the `links` list is also a list.

A dictionary can't contain a list as a key, since dictionaries are based on a hash table and lists can't be hashed. Tuples can be hashed though, and they're very similar to lists, so you could try converting the list to a tuple.

Also you can't append to something that doesn't exist yet. The most straight-forward approach is to handle the two cases separately, assuming you want to capture every match and add it to a list. You could also use a `defaultdict` which would handle the first-time addition automatically, as suggested in the comments.

```
if tuple(links[i]) not in linedict:
    linedict[tuple(links[i])] = [prob]
else:
    linedict[tuple(links[i])].append(prob)
```

Comment: I tried with above solution but error is still coming as Key Error

Comment: You could probably make it slightly more efficient by doing the cast to a tuple at the start of the for-loop, rather than doing it (and the array access) twice.

Comment: Also if ``lindict`` doesn't already contain a list at the key, trying to do ``append`` to it will result in a key-error. You'd have to make ``linedict`` a ``defaultdict(list)``

Comment: @shanky I made an edit - I didn't realize right away that you had more than one error.

Comment: @Mark Ransom thanks for solution my code is working perfectly now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way using defaultdict from collections. I also did some few changes to your code that should make it clearer.

```
import collections

# use a default dict
linedict = collections.defaultdict(list)
# create your list of lists as before but convert them to tuples
links = [tuple(links[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(links), 2)]

# iterate over the lists directly
for link in links:
    print link
    linedict[link].append(prob)  # it's a default dict so you can append directly!
```