# "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" yet I'm trying to only slice the value of the list, not use the list itself

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

I've been having issues trying to create a dictionary by using the values from a list.

```
alphabetList = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphabetList.append(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
alphabetDict = {}
def makeAlphabetDict (Dict, x):
    count = 0
    while count <= len(alphabetList):
        item1 = x[(count + (len(alphabetList) / 2))]
        item2 = item1
        Dict[item1] = item2
        count += 1
makeAlphabetDict(alphabetDict , alphabetList)
```

Which returns:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

[I tried here and other similar questions yet I still can't see why Python thinks I'm trying to use the list, rather than just a slice from a list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list?newreg=3517eb0266a44058914cc4573bd97963)

Comment: Yeh, I edited that shortly after posting. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list contains a *nested* list:

```
alphabetList.append(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
```

You now have a list with `['a', 'b', ..., 'z', ['a', 'b', ..., 'z']]`. It is that last element in the outer list that causes your problem.

You'd normally would use `list.extend()` to add additional elements:

```
alphabetList.extend(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

You are using `string.ascii_lowercase` twice there; perhaps you meant to use `ascii_uppercase` for one of those strings instead? Even so, your code always uses the same character for both key and value so it wouldn't really matter here.

If you are trying to map lowercase to uppercase or vice-versa, just use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and `dict()`:

```
alphabetDict = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase))
```

where `zip()` produces pairs of characters, and `dict()` takes those pairs as key-value pairs. The above produces a dictionary mapping lowercase ASCII characters to uppercase:

```
>>> import string
>>> dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase))
{'u': 'U', 'v': 'V', 'o': 'O', 'k': 'K', 'n': 'N', 'm': 'M', 't': 'T', 'l': 'L', 'h': 'H', 'e': 'E', 'p': 'P', 'i': 'I', 'b': 'B', 'x': 'X', 'q': 'Q', 'g': 'G', 'd': 'D', 'r': 'R', 'z': 'Z', 'c': 'C', 'w': 'W', 'a': 'A', 'y': 'Y', 'j': 'J', 'f': 'F', 's': 'S'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to get a list that iterates the alphabet in lower case _twice_ without spending forever trying to type it out by hand. would list.extend allow me to do this?

Comment: list.extend will work fine. However, dict will have them only once.

Comment: @ChrisHill: not sure what you are trying to do then, because your function then ignores the first half of that list altogether, and sets each key twice (keys in a dictionary are *unique*, so you'd be replacing the key the second time around). You'd end up with the same result as `dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase))`, that is, with a dictionary mapping lowercase characters to the exact same lowercase letter. Not a very useful mapping.

Comment: @ChrisHill: but yes, `list.extend()` will add the elements of the argument as separate elements to the list. Your list grows by that number of elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, I didn't realise that. I'll have to look over it. Thanks for warning me, you may have just save me a lot of frustration ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn Pieters noted, you have problem with the list append that adds a list within your other list. You can add two list in any of the following ways for simplicity:

```
alphabetList = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphabetList += list(string.ascii_lowercase)
# Adds two lists; same as that of alphabetList.extend(alphabetList)

alphabetList = list(string.ascii_lowercase) * 2
# Just for your use case to iterate twice over the alphabets
```

In either case, your alphabetDict will have only 26 alphabets and not 52 as you cannot have repeated keys within the dict.