# Python 3 Values of a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a blackjack game and need to collect the score of all the cards the player has. When i use the following code I get unhashable type: 'list' error.

Cards is a dictionary that holds all the cards and their respective blackjack points score and p a dictionary which holds the players cards (as they would be keys in the cards dictionary.

```
score = cards[list(p.values())]
```

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: lists cant be dictionary keys, however tuples can. Try that instead.

Comment: why don't you show us how p and cards look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: did my answer help you or do you need anything else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that lists in python can't be used as dictionary keys.

What you want is to access the dictionary values for each element of that list, so try to use a list comprehension.

```
score = sum(cards[c] for c in p.values())
```

Comment: remove the [] inside sum() and I dont think the list() is necessary either

Answer (score 1):

A list can never be the key of a dictionary.

[Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

Answer (score 1):

You got that error just because of you are trying to use `list` as dictionary keys, which is prohibited in Python. [to know why look at @SyntaxError answer]

try following code instead of yours

```
score = sum(cards[value_of_p] for value_of_p in p.values())
```