# python TypeError unhashable type list

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
equipment_element = {'equipment_name', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this list?

I'm trying to work backwards from this post [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

but my key is not a list, my value is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TBH, I find it confusing that dictionaries and sets use basically identical syntax. With two elements, the only thing that makes it possible to distinguish between a dictionary and a set is the symbol in the middle: `:` or `,`... Even worse, `{}` constructs an empty dictionary, while it seems more logical for it to construct a set.

Comment: @ForceBru the python docs recommend using `set()` to create empty sets. I guess they ran out of (types of) braces.    

***while it seems more logical for it to construct a set.***

actually with just a few weeks of experience in python you get used to the fact that `dicts` are far widely used than `sets` and to the default behaviour of `{}`

Answer (score 3):

It's not a dictionary, it's a set.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create set, not a dictionary

Modify it as follows. Replace the `,` in between to `:`

```
equipment_element = {'equipment_name': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

Comment: haha! Whoops, a colon the difference between victory and defeat

Answer (score 0):

maybe you were looking for this syntax

```
equipment_element = {'equipment_name': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

or

```
equipment_element = dict('equipment_name' = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

or

```
equipment_element = dict([('equipment_name', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0])])
```

This syntax is for creating a set:

```
equipment_element = {'equipment_name', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```