# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, csv, arrays, list

I'm attempting to use Python to read a CSV file containing thousands of email addresses then create a list of all of the duplicates. Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv

input_file='combined.csv'
original_list=[]
duplicate_list=[]

def readcsv(input_file):
    ifile = open(combined, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=";")

    rownum = 0
    for row in reader:
        original_list.append (row)
        rownum += 1

    ifile.close()
    original_list.sort()
    return original_list

(readcsv(input_file))

seen_set = set()
duplicate_set = set(x for x in original_list if x in seen_set or seen_set.add(x))
unique_set = seen_set - duplicate_set

print (duplicate_set)
print (unique_set)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: Ok. And when you google'd that error message which inevitably led you back to Stack Overflow, what did you find?

Comment: `duplicate_set = set(x for x in original_list if x in seen_set or seen_set.add(x))` this code is broken. `seen_set.add(x)` is `None`. Your error is caused because `x` is a list but even if you wrap `x` in `tuple(x)` the code still won't work as expected. `set`s are always unique, why do you need a duplicate set?

Comment: I found that I have a problem with lists vs dictionaries perhaps, but due to the fact that I'm a novice programmer I asked the question generally in case I'm not understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of (which even without the `TypeError` is still bad python for the reasons explained in the comments):

```
seen_set = set()
duplicate_set = set(x for x in original_list if x in seen_set or seen_set.add(x))
unique_set = seen_set - duplicate_set
```

literally all you need is

```
# first just use set to grab all the possible elements (make lists hashable by
# passing through tuple) -- this is a set comprehension 
seen_set = {tuple(x) for x in original_list}

# the duplicates are just ones with counts > 1
duplicate_set = {t for t in seen_set if original_list.count(list(t)) > 1}

unique_set = seen_set - duplicate_set
```

---

You function can also simply be written as

```
def readcsv(input_file):
    ifile = open(combined, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=";")
    return sorted(reader)  # don't mutate global variables!

original_list = readcsv(input_file)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've made these changes. Now the script runs without errors but seems to be running *forever at this line: dups5.py(21): duplicate_set = {t for t in unique_set if original_list.count(list(t)) > 1}

Comment: It's not infinite looping. If you have a large data / a slow computer then there are more efficient implementations (mostly using `for` loops and counters) but you'll have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: Excellent, no problem waiting. Thank you so much.