# Unable to convert list into set, raises "unhashable type: 'list' " error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

So I'm trying to find all sub-lists of a list and here is what I have now. I'm new to Python and I don't understand why " Q3_ans=set(ans)" raises an error. I've tried to convert a list to set before and it works.

```
def f2(seq):
    '''
    This is the base case of the recursion from function all_sublists
    '''
    assert len(seq)==2
    assert isinstance(x,list)
    a,b=seq
    return [[a],[b],[a,b]]


def all_sublists(x):
    '''
    This function will generate all of the sublists of a list, not including the empty one, using recursion
    '''
    assert isinstance(x,list)
    ans=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
        for j in range(1,len(x)):
            temp=[x[i],x[j]]
            temp=[f2(temp)]
            ans.extend(temp)
    Q3_ans=set(ans) 
    return Q3_ans
```

Here is the error when I run my code
    y=[1,2,3,4,5]

```
all_sublists(y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-f8b1bb0a7001> in <module>
----> 1 all_sublists(y)

<ipython-input-106-84f4f752e98e> in all_sublists(x)
     10             temp=[f2(temp)]
     11             ans.extend(temp)
---> 12     Q3_ans=set(ans)
     13     return Q3_ans

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: I wanted to do recursion at first but then I changed my mind, please don't mind the comment

Comment: What's the error you see? Please provide full traceback [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52805262/edit).

Comment: Your list contains lists, which are not hashable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the essence of the problem:

```
>>> set([[["a"],["b"],["a","b"]]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So, what does that mean?

[`set([iterable])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

> Return a new set ... object whose elements are taken from iterable. **The elements of a set must be hashable**.

[*hashable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; **mutable
>   containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not**.

The keywords here are [*mutable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mutable)

> Mutable objects can change their value but keep their id().

and [*immutable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable)

> An object with a fixed value. Immutable objects include numbers,
>   strings and tuples. Such an object cannot be altered. A new object has
>   to be created if a different value has to be stored. They play an
>   important role in places where a constant hash value is needed, for
>   example as a key in a dictionary.

So, you can't use a `list` as `set` element. A `tuple` would work:

```
>>> set([(("a"),("b"),("a","b"))])
{('a', 'b', ('a', 'b'))}
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up. There are lots of references to converting lists to sets using the code `set(<list>)`. How can that be?

Comment: @PProteus The conversion of a list to a set that you are referring to is valid, but this list must not contain further list elements, i.e. `set(<list(<list>)>)` causes the TypeError. Try e.g. `set([1,2,3])` and `set([[1],2,3])`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can figure out why, mutable types like lists can't be hashable, so can't be converted to a `set`. You can try returning `tuple` instead; an immutable counterpart for `list`:

```
def f2(seq):
    assert len(seq)==2
    assert isinstance(x, tuple) # what's `x` actually?
    a, b = seq
    return ((a), (b), (a,b))

def all_sublists(x):
    assert isinstance(x, list)
    ans = []
    for i in range(0, len(x) - 1):
        for j in range(1, len(x)):
            temp = (x[i], x[j])
            temp = [f2(temp)]
            ans.extend(temp)
    Q3_ans = set(tuple(ans))
    return Q3_ans
```

then

```
all_sublists([1, 2, 3])
```

You can read more about [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) type in the documentation.