# Why Can You Sometimes Convert a List to Set in Python, but Other Times You Can't?

Tags: python

In [some corners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805381/6608148) of StackOverflow, it is well-known that you cannot convert a list into a set, because it is "unhashable". In [other corners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/6608148), it is well-known that you can convert a list into a set. Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: You can convert a list to a set. You can't put a list *in* a set.

Comment: Understanding that a `set` expects an *iterable* is enough. In the second case the elements of the iterable are integers, whereas in the first they are lists, which are not hashable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy comes from using a nested list, i.e. `[[<a>, <b>, <c>]]`.

`Set()` can handle a single-layer list; it treats every element of a list as an argument in the set constructor—but when nesting lists, it receives the inner list as a single argument. It then wants to make a set with a single element, containing the inner list. Because that inner list is still a list (it's not broken apart, as a single-layer list would be), it's unhashable, as described in the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805381/6608148).