# Type Error: unhashable type: 'list' (using dictionary)

Tags: python

I am getting this error in my code `unhashable type: 'list'`

I have a text file with this input:

```
hokejistov hokej
strelena strela
trener trenuje
```

I want to divide words to 2 rows. First row will consist with first words. And Second row will consist with second words. Then I need to divide words to signs. This part is working but then I need to use dictionary `(mapka = {'h':1,'o':2,'k':3, 'e':4, 'j':5, 'i':6, 's':7, 't':8,'v':9,'r':10, 'l':11, 'n':12, 'a':13, 'u':14})` .

On Output I want to get this:

```
first = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9], [7, 8, 10, 4, 11, 4, 12, 13], [8, 10, 4, 12, 4, 10]]
second = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 10, 4, 11, 13], [8, 10, 4, 12, 14, 5, 4]]
```

this is my code

```py
data = [line.strip() for line in open("mamradhokej.txt",'r')]
mapka = {'h':1,'o':2,'k':3, 'e':4, 'j':5, 'i':6, 's':7, 't':8,'v':9, 
        'r':10, 'l':11, 'n':12, 'a':13, 'u':14}

first = [[word.lower() for word in text.split()[0]]for text in data]
second = [[word.lower() for word in text.split()[1]]for text in data]

print(first)
print(second)

map(mapka.get, first)
[mapka[k] for k in first] #here i am getting Type error: unhashable type: 'list'.
```

Comment: `k` is a list so the error makes sense

Comment: Dictionary keys must be immutable types to keep the dictionary sane. If you need to use a collection as a key, use `tuple` instead of `list`. But I don't think this is actually what you want.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here (same error with `list` in `set`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805381/1619432

Comment: `first` is a list of lists, so `k` in `mapka[k]` is a list, for example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9]`, so `mapka[k]` is not what you want, because there is no such key in `mapka`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why are you getting this error?

Dictionary keys must be hashable objects.

In order for an object to be hashable, it should be an instance of a class that implements `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods.

Objects of `list` type are not hashable.

The reason you are getting this error is because `first` is a list of lists.

*Side note: hashable does not mean immutable in python*

## Solution

You need a nested iteration:

```py
first_output = [[mapka[letter] for letter in word] for word in first]
```

And similarly for `second`. You could also loop through first and second, to avoid code duplication

Answer (score 0):

As the `mapka` will be applied over **character**, you should iterate at the character level.

In python iterating a **string**, results in iterating over characters.

So this should work:

```py
data = ["hokejistov hokej", "strelena strela", "trener trenuje"] 
second = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 10, 4, 11, 13], [8, 10, 4, 12, 14, 5, 4]]
mapka = {'h':1,'o':2,'k':3, 'e':4, 'j':5, 'i':6, 's':7, 't':8,'v':9, 
    'r':10, 'l':11, 'n':12, 'a':13, 'u':14}

first = [[word.lower() for word in text.split()[0]]for text in data]
second = [[word.lower() for word in text.split()[1]]for text in data]

print([[mapka[letter] for letter in word] for word in first])
print([[mapka[letter] for letter in word] for word in second])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with lists only:

```
# pretend to read your file
data = ["hokejistov hokej","strelena strela","trener trenuje"]

# a dictionary is not strictly needed here
mapka = "hokejistvrlnau"

# convert lines to columns
columns = []
for line in data:
    for i,word in enumerate(line.split()):
        try:
            columns[i].append(word)
        except IndexError:
            columns.append([word])

print(columns) # [['hokejistov', 'strelena', 'trener'], ['hokej', 'strela', 'trenuje']]

# look up each letter
for column in columns:
    print( [ [mapka.index(letter)+1  for letter in word] for word in column] )

# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9], [7, 8, 10, 4, 11, 4, 12, 13], [8, 10, 4, 12, 4, 10]]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 10, 4, 11, 13], [8, 10, 4, 12, 14, 5, 4]]
```