# Unhashable list when the list is too big in Python

Tags: python, list, hash

I have two dataframes (both quite large), `df` and `df3`, and the following line of code:

```
  set1 = df3['JointObligorID'].unique()
  set2 = df['JointObligorID'].unique()
  set3 = list(set(set1).intersection(set2)) 

  # slice df3 by keeping what's in set3 
  df4 = df3[df3['JointObligorID'].isin([set3])]
```

Once I reach the last step, however, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list) did not work, either because there were specific to the questions or some answers where not general enough (my list - `set3` - is too big)

Can someone help fixing this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a list of list instead use

```
df4 = df3[df3['JointObligorID'].isin(set3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want hashable list-like structure, you can use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=tuple#tuples-and-sequences):

`set3 = tuple(set(set1).intersection(set2))`

instead of:

`set3 = list(set(set1).intersection(set2))`