# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' pandas python

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

**df** is the database with weather as column

```
 Weather
 Rain, freezing cold
 Rain, and thunder
 Thunderstorm, and dust
 Drizzle, for half an hour
 Drizzle, for sometime
 Rain, non stop
 Slight rain
```

**Code**

```
heavy_rain_indicator = ['Rain,','Thunderstorm,',]
light_rain_indicator = ['Drizzle,','Slight rain']

df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = (df['Weather'].str.contains(heavy_rain_indicator))
df['Light Rain Indicator'] = (df['Weather'].str.contains(light_rain_indicator))
```

**Expected output:**

```
 Weather                  Heavy Rain Indicator    Light Rain Indicator
 Rain, freezing cold         TRUE                      FALSE
 Rain, and thunder           TRUE                      FALSE
 Thunderstorm, and dust       TRUE                      FALSE
 Drizzle, for half an hour   FALSE                     TRUE
 Drizzle, for sometime       FALSE                     TRUE
 Rain, non stop              TRUE                      FALSE
 Slight rain                 FALSE                     TRUE
```

**Actual output**

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
 ----> 4     df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = (df['Weather'].str.contains(heavy_rain_indicator))
```

I want the columns Heavy rain indicator to be `TRUE` when heavy rain indicators are present and light rain indicator to be `TRUE` when light rain indicators are present

Someone suggested to use `isin` (and then deleted the post) but I cannot type the exact expression, so for heavy rain indicator for eg I want all values beginning with Rain, to be in heavy indicator column and so on. Pls answer accordingly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19371358/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13675296/11301900

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More pandas answer:

```py
df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].str.startswith(tuple(heavy_rain_indicator))
df['Light Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].str.startswith(tuple(light_rain_indicator))
```

or if you want find cases not only from the beginning:

```py
df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].str.contains('|'.join(heavy_rain_indicator))
df['Light Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].str.contains('|'.join(light_rain_indicator))
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.contains` takes argument as `string` but you are passing the list

You can use `list comprehension` with `any` like below:

```
df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = [any(i.lower() in j.lower() for i in heavy_rain_indicator) for j in df["Weather"].values]

df['Light Rain Indicator'] = [any(i.lower() in j.lower() for i in light_rain_indicator) for j in df["Weather"].values]
```

Comment: Why are you using `.values`?  It shouldn't be a huge issue here, but the correct way of performing a case-insensitive comparison is using `str.casefold()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```py
def get_TF(x, info_list):
    return any([True for i in info_list if i in x])
heavy_rain_indicator = ['Rain,','Thunderstorm,']
light_rain_indicator = ['Drizzle,','Slight rain']

df['Heavy Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].apply(lambda x : get_TF(x, heavy_rain_indicator))
df['Light Rain Indicator'] = df['Weather'].apply(lambda x : get_TF(x, light_rain_indicator))
df


                     Weather  Heavy Rain Indicator  Light Rain Indicator
0        Rain, freezing cold                  True                 False
1          Rain, and thunder                  True                 False
2     Thunderstorm, and dust                  True                 False
3  Drizzle, for half an hour                 False                  True
4      Drizzle, for sometime                 False                  True
5             Rain, non stop                  True                 False
6                Slight rain                 False                  True
```

Comment: You really don't need `.apply()`, an entire function, and a lambda for this. Why use `any([True for i in info_list if i in x])` instead of just `any(i in x for i in info_list)` ?