# How to fix TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'?

Tags: python

```
def game_popularity(gen_to_mov, mov_to_avg, n = 5):
    top_n_rated_games = {}
    for i in gtom:
        if avg_rat[gtom[i]] == n:
            top_n_rated_games[i] = gtom[i]
    return top_n_rated_games
print(game_popularity(gtom, avg_rat))
```

returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/how-to-overcome-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: most popular game in a given genre

Comment: You need to show more code; What is gtom? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may want to change `for i in gtom:` to `for i in range(len(gtom)):`. But it's hard to tell without seeing more code.