# How to use applymap lambda with two conditions

Tags: python, lambda, duplicates, typeerror, python-applymap

I'd like to find duplicated rows in a Pandas dataframe. When I use `df.duplicated()` it returns the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

To resolve this error, I tried the following:

```
df2 = df[df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x).duplicated()]
```

However, I receive a new but similar error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

Does anyone know how I can use `applymap lambda` with two conditions? (the conditions are `if isinstance(x, list)` OR `if isinstance(x, dict)`)?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the sample of the data (first few rows of the df):
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that df is a pandas dataframe type? check for type(df). I normally use df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=[X,Y,Z]), ]. I do not have much experience with applymap, but with apply, I also use axis, apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1).

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you could use `.applymap` to transform your list into tuples, a hashable type that will allow you to use `.duplicated()`

Comment: @Rockbar: yes it is a dataframe (returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame). It's a twitter data retrieved in json format (nested json)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: @rehaqds: sure. I updated my post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/how-to-overcome-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt not really, because I'd like to know how to use two conditions with `applymap lambda` (to include both `list` and `dict` types in the condition)

Comment: The problem is probably the dict in the list. I would write a function to tackle the "referenced_tweets" first. Since you know the structure there, you can spare the if else question, and write a specific unwrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `apply` you create a column with dictionary in it, the issue is that the method `duplicated` use hashing to compare values and in Python dictionaries (and lists) are not hashable.
But strings are hashable so you could add `.astype(str)`:

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x).astype(str).duplicated()
```